# Initialize a 2D array with zero in the constructor C++

Tags: c++, arrays

What is the best way to initialize a large 2D array with 0 in the constructor? I would like to do this without having to loop through my array, if possible.

Comment: this would be memset func

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use memset. For example:

```
int a[10][10]; 
memset(a, 0, sizeof(int)*10*10);
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, use a `std::vector` instead of an array.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2d(100, std::vector<int>(50, 0));
```

The resulting two-dimensional vector will contain 100 vectors, each containing 50 zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you allocated your "2D" array. But this is basically how I would initialize any large block of data.

```
int data[10000];
memset(data,0,sizeof(int)*10000);
```

Comment: or just do **void *calloc(size_t nelements, size_t bytes);** to allocate memory for 2D array which allocates a region of memory large enough to hold "n elements" of "size" bytes each. Also initializes contents of memory to zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is 1D, 2D, 3D, xxD array or any other structure you may just do the following:

```
memset(pointer_to_your_object, 0, sizeof(your_object));
```

but **memset** in general can set memory area with any value so if that is just setting to zero you may use some of the macros that are out there - they are all called like zeromem, zeromemory etc:

[ZeroMemory on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before for a 1D array, I assume something similar for 2D?

For a constructor:

```
 class MyClass {
   int a[100];
   MyClass() : a() // all zeros
   {
     // stuff
   }
 };
```